# badimageformatexception could not load file or assembly when publich x64 application to IIS when “Enable 32-bit Applications” is set to True

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Good day!

I can not even publish a standard initial MVC application with  x64 configuration.
When i set the value of “Enable 32-bit Applications” to False in IIS AppPool settings everything works well, but when i set the value of “Enable 32-bit Applications” to True i get an error. 
here's a screencast (sorry that the IIS have russian interface): http://www.screencast.com/t/Kf0mpM9uFa

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Nothing is wrong, if you enable 32 bits app on the pool it can't execute x64 code.

Comment: is It not possible to allow the execution of 32 and 64 bit applications in a one Application Pool? I have the same problem on a third-party hosting service and they try to convince me that it should work

Comment: If it's IIS 7 or higher yes, but not with that param, it configures the AppPool globally. Take a look at this: http://serverfault.com/questions/82723/is-it-possible-to-mix-32-and-64-bit-application-pools-on-iis6

Comment: Thanks for the help